# Pruning trials in Optuna using both threshold and PatientMedianPruner

Tags: threshold, optuna

I am using `MedianPruner` (with patience) in Optuna. Sometimes a trial begins to diverge, and I want to stop it before it continues. I *would* use `ThresholdPruner`, but I can't as I am already using `MedianPruner`.

What I could do is manually prune the trial using something like:

```
def objective(trial):
  ...
  #Handle pruning the usual way in Optuna
  trial.report(accuracy, epoch)
  if trial.should_prune():
    raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()

  #Now handle MANUAL pruning using a custom threshold
  if error_rate > 1e10: #trial has diverged/failed, so prune
    raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()

   ...
   return error_rate
```

However, I have found that this 'hack' seems to negatively affect the sampler, as the resulting top 10 models end up being less good than without the hack (mostly - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76525684/21896093)).

I could perhaps implement a custom pruner that combines both the MedianPruner+patience with my required threshold, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to filter out divergent trials.

Main reason for doing this is that the outlier trial ends up drowning out all of trials in the visualisations on Optuna Dashboard.